# Access original data from before an edit with ag-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When using the ag-Grid API to access data, only the edited data can be found. Is the original data preserved anywhere? For example would it be located in:

```
api.getRowNode(id)
```

This could be useful for example when wanting to color a cell that has been edited, using the comparison of the values to alter the value of the color.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the changes using `onCellValueChanged` function defined in your grid settings:

```
var gridOptions = {
    ...
    onCellValueChanged: function(params) {
      console.log(params.oldValue);
      console.log(params.newValue);
      ...
    }
}
```

As per ag-grid documentation - `onCellValueChanged` is a callback used to run an action, after cell value has been modified and contains the same parameters as the `valueSetter` together with the `newValue`.

Comment: I am experimenting with saving the other values in my own structure. I am now hooking into the callback you suggested. Will update when I have a working example.